# Partition Items by Item# and Location in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Given that I have the following dataset in TempTable:

```
Item        Item Desc        Location       Qty      LeasedQty
----------------------------------------------------------------
IT2250      1/2CANTOP         NYC            1.00     30.00
IT5550      FCM 2K            NYC            6.00      8.00
IT2075      HPTL 750          LA             4.00     44.00
IT12506     DOUBLE DOOR 10"   CALI          60.00      0.00
IT3606      BAG180            CALI          25.00      0.00
IT3606      BAG180            NYC           20.00     40.00
IT3606      BAG180            LA             5.00     45.00
IT50        2K                NYC            6.00      8.00
IT50        2K                LA             4.00     44.00
IT50        2K                CALI          60.00      0.00
```

How can I partition this data so that It will be Like the following:

```
Item        Item Desc        Location       Qty      LeasedQty    RNK
----------------------------------------------------------------------
IT2250      1/2CANTOP         NYC            1.00     30.00        1
IT5550      FCM 2K            NYC            6.00      8.00        2
IT2075      HPTL 750          LA             4.00     44.00        3
IT12506     DOUBLE DOOR 10"   CALI          60.00      0.00        4
IT3606      BAG180            CALI          25.00      0.00        5
IT3606      BAG180            NYC           20.00     40.00        5
IT3606      BAG180            LA             5.00     45.00        5
IT50        2K                NYC            6.00      8.00        6
IT50        2K                LA             4.00     44.00        6
IT50        2K                CALI          60.00      0.00        6
```

Basically, I want the data to group by each item and gather the TOP 20 items based on the QTY (DESCENDING)

Comment: both tables are same except rnk is added and also rnk is not by qty or item sorting, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @RADAR. The second table has just added a simple count to Group by ITEM (Regardless of Location). So Then Would need to order these by Qty and Select TOP 20 ITEMs where RANK <=20.

Answer (score 0):

To get that rank this will help you

```
SELECT Dense_rank()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY Item) rnk,
       *
FROM   TempTable
```

Added to get top 20 records

```
SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM   (SELECT Dense_rank()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY Item,qty desc) rnk,
               *
        FROM   TempTable) a
WHERE  rnk <= 20
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly @Peadeep. Now is there a way I can do that and also have the qty ordered by DESC?

Comment: @user2684009 - check now

Comment: That doesn't work. All it did was select the TOP 20 Items. But it didn't re-order the RANK by quantity DESC and then get TOP 20 Items

Comment: @user2684009 - moved qty with in rank check now. It will be really helpful if you post the final expected output.